# NERDTree E704 error on opening a directory

Tags: vim, nerdtree

When autostarting NERDTree using this config:

```
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 && !exists("s:std_in") | exe 'NERDTree' | endif
```

I was getting error E704.

Answer (score 0):

Update your NERDTree plugin. In my case it was executing vim-plug update command:

```
:PlugUpdate
```

Comment: You answered your own question within the same minute it was posted.